# R: sapply printing results

Tags: r, sapply

I have code that is doing this:

```
sapply(unique(groups.50),function(g)data$SEQUENCE_ID[groups.50 == g])
```

But in the RGui window, I can only scroll up to see some of the results. The first 10 or so doesn't show in the window (probably because my data is so large). How do I get it to show all of it, or alternatively, how do I print the first 10 results?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into `?split` and/or `?tapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scrolling through large datasets, the `page` function with `method='print'` is also pretty handy. It has the added benefit of not cluttering your command history with output.

Comment: If `d` is your variable, `page(d, method='print')`.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output of your function is a vector, save it to an object and then subset:

```
a <- sapply(unique(groups.50),function(g)data$SEQUENCE_ID[groups.50 == g])
a[1:10]
```

Or use `head`:

```
head(sapply(unique(groups.50),function(g)data$SEQUENCE_ID[groups.50 == g]),n=10)
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but one of my results is so long that it doesn't print out every item. This is a cluster analysis, and one of the clusters has 20K items. So even if I did something like n=1, that cluster doesn't print out entirely because it's so large. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `a` a list of data frames? My guess is that you can do something like `sapply(a,head)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
x<-sapply(unique(groups.50),function(g)data$SEQUENCE_ID[groups.50 == g])
head(x)
```

But you should probably be using tapply instead?

Comment: Do you have a link to the use of tapply? I'm still new to R.